# scratchpad - Keep getting "undefined" in the output on console.

Tags: javascript, console

```
function largerNum (a,b){
  if (a>b){
    console.log("The larger number of " +a, "and " +b, "is " +a,".");
  }
  else{
        console.log("The larger number of " +a, "and " +b, "is " +b,".");
  }
}
console.log(largerNum (5,12));
```

the output shows - The larger number of 6 and 12 is 12 
undefined

Answer (score 0):

because there is no return in your function and so `console.log(largerNum (5,12))` gives undefined

make your function to return something

chnage to

```
function largerNum (a,b){
  if (a>b){
    return "The larger number of " + a + " and " + b + " is " + a + "."

  }
  else{
      return "The larger number of " + a + " and " + b + " is " + b + "."

  }
}
console.log(largerNum (5,12));
```

Comment: function largerNum (a,b){
  if (a>b){
    
    console.log("The larger number of " +a, "and " +b, "is " +a,".");
    
  }
  else{
        console.log("The larger number of " +a, "and " +b, "is " +b,".");
  }
  
  return largerNum;
}
console.log(largerNum (5,12));

Comment: getting "unavailable" now.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the function is not explicitly returning anything, it return `undefined` by default

```js
function largerNum(a, b) {
  if (a > b) {
    console.log("The larger number of " + a, "and " + b, "is " + a, ".");
  } else {
    console.log("The larger number of " + a, "and " + b, "is " + b, ".");
  }
  // this function is not returning anything
}
console.log(largerNum(5, 12));
```

Comment: I got it. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning any value from your `largerNum` function so the default return value of `undefined` is being returned. You could refactor your code like this.

> note: the string is concatenated with `+` rather than using `,` to separate arguments to `console.log`

```js
function largerNum(a, b) {
  if (a > b) {
    return "The larger number of " + a + " and " + b + " is " + a + "."
  }
  else {
    return "The larger number of " + a + " and " + b + " is " + b + "."
  }
}

console.log(
  largerNum(5, 12)
)
console.log(
  largerNum(13, 42)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `larger()` function doesn't return any values so you are passing `null` to the last `console.log()` statement.

```
function largerNum (a,b){
    if (a>b){
        return a;
    } else {
        return b;
    }
}
console.log(
     "The larger number of " + a + ", and " + b + ", is " + 
      largerNum(a,b) + "."
);
```

Should work

Answer (score 0):

Because you don't need to `console.log` when invoking the function: your function returns nothing, and you see additional `undefined`. Just remove `console.log()` wrapper from `console.log(largerNum (5,12))`:

```js
function largerNum (a,b){
  if (a>b){
    console.log("The larger number of " +a, "and " +b, "is " +a,".");
  }
  else{
    console.log("The larger number of " +a, "and " +b, "is " +b,".");
  }
}
largerNum(5,12);
```

Or return the value from function and log the function invocation:

```js
function largerNum (a,b){
  if (a>b){
    return "The larger number of " +a+ " and " +b+ " is " +a+ ".";
  }
  else{
    return "The larger number of " +a+ " and " +b+ " is " +b+ ".";
  }
}
console.log(largerNum(5,12));
```